# Fiddling with Java Graphics, this worked _once_

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm trying to draw on a JPanel more directly, hence the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
public class px{
    JFrame F=new JFrame();
    JPanel P=new JPanel();
    public px(){
        P.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
        F.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        F.add(P);
        F.pack();
        F.setResizable(false);
        F.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void sq(int x,int y,int c){
        Graphics2D G=(Graphics2D)P.getGraphics();
        G.setPaint(Color.red);
        G.fill(new Rectangle(x*10,y*10,10,10));
        P.paint(P.getGraphics());
        F.revalidate();
    }
    public static void main (String[]args){
        px X=new px();
        X.sq(1,1,0);
    }
}
```

However the damned little red square has only appeared once, might have been a runtime error or a botched compile.

Comment: The bottom line: **Never call `getGraphics()` on a `Component`**

Answer (score 2):

- Override `paintComponent()` method of `JPanel` for custom painting where you can get the `Graphics` object as method parameters.
- Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent()` in overridden `paintComponent()` method.
- Override `getPreferredSize()` to set the preferred size of the `JPanel` in case of custom painting.

> For more info read [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and try sample code as well.

**Note:** Follow Java Naming convention.

sample code:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ...
        // custom painting code goes here
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(..., ...);
    }
}
```